# Skipping range of rows after header through pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I know the argument `usecols` in `pandas.read_excel()` allows you to select specific columns.

Say, I read an Excel file in with `pandas.read_excel()`. My excel spreadsheet has 1161 rows. I want to keep the 1st row (with index 0), and skip rows 2:337. Seems like the argument `skiprows` works only when 0 indexing is involved. I tried several different ways but my code always produces an output where *all* my 1161 rows are read rather than only after the 337th row on. Such as this:

```py
documentationscore_dataframe = pd.read_excel("Documentation Score Card_17DEC2015 Rev 2 17JAN2017.xlsx",
                                        sheet_name = "Sheet1",
                                        skiprows = "336",
                                        usecols = "H:BD")
```

Here is another attempt:

```py
documentationscore_dataframe = pd.read_excel("Documentation Score Card_17DEC2015 Rev 2 17JAN2017.xlsx",
                                        sheet_name = "Sheet1",
                                        skiprows = "1:336",
                                        usecols = "H:BD")
```

I would like the dataframe to exclude rows 2 through 337 in the original Excel import.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) for `pandas.read_excel`, `skiprows` must be list-like.

Try this instead to exclude rows 1 to 336 inclusive:

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx",
                   sheet_name = "Sheet1",
                   skiprows = range(1, 337),
                   usecols = "H:BD")
```

**Note**: `range` constructor is considered `list`-like for this purpose, so no explicit list conversion is necessary.

Comment: +1 for expliciting it's list-like, resolved my problem to read the header but skip first row just after it (`pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=[1])`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a function to `skiprows=`. For example, to skip the first 336 rows (after the header row):

```py
df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=lambda x: 1<=x<=336)
```